# ALTER COLUMN NOT NULL, not enough space in the log file

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run the following DDL

```sql
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_name] ALTER COLUMN [Value] [float] NOT NULL
```

This generates a large amount of log file data, and there is not enough space for it on the server.

Is it possible to somehow reduce the information being logged?

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU15) (KB4495257)

Comment: Find more space. You're trying to modify every row in that table, which means *every* row has to be written to the log to allow rollbacks if something goes wrong like ... running out of space. Or you cancel the query, it times out, the server goes down etc. If you haven't taken a transaction log backup for a long time the transaction log is probably far bigger than it needs to be

Comment: You can't reduce required log space (SQL server needs to store entire table there), but (depend on drive configuration) you sometimes can add another log file (ldf) to another disk; in virtual environments you may be able just to increase drive size (temporarily).

Comment: If your db recovery model is `SIMPLE` or `BULK_LOGGED`, you could create a new table as a minimally logged operation using `SELECT...INTO`, coercing the NOT NULL with `ISNULL(value, 0) AS Value`. Then drop the ooriginal table and recreated indexes/constraiants.

Answer (score 3):

you might find it faster to create a new table, truncate the old, and then re-insert:

```
select t.*
into temp_my_table
from [dbo].[table_name] t;

truncate table [dbo].[table_name];  -- back it up first!

alter table [dbo].[table_name] alter column [Value] [float] NOT NULL

insert into [dbo].[table_name]
select t.*
from temp_my_table t;
```

You may have to pay attention if you have insert triggers or identity columns.